# Publication during my intermediate work

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, thesis, paper-submission

I work on wireless communication topic for my thesis and want to published some my intermediate work on my thesis.

There are conferences, Workshops, posters, magazines (did I miss something?). All of them has a deadline for paper submission, which are 2-6 months yearly then the conference/workshop itself.

I search the list of conferences in 2023 on ieee website, but most of deadline were passed for submission in this year. Did I search wrong way? Should I search somewhere else?

Could you share your experience how you search conferences for publishing your work? Some advices how to write researches paper which were useful for you?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Both [IEEE](https://www.ieee.org) and [ACM](https://www.acm.org) have multiple conferences each year and many are held annually. If you are a member of either or both organizations they typically email announcements of upcoming conference deadlines (call for papers).

Their publications, such as Communications of the ACM, also give notice of upcoming conference deadlines. If you aren't a member then you can probably find these publications in any university library.

Note that "Student Membership" is typically available at a lower fee than is paid by professors.

The organizations also have SIGs (Special Interest Groups) that focus on a particular area. Membership in a SIG will bring you email of upcoming events, including conference deadlines.